# CBT Hook not working in Windows Vista

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to use a CBT hook to receive HCBT_MOVESIZE notifications. It works fine for all applications when I run my program from a folder on my desktop.  When I install the application to the "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86" folder I only receive notifications for my own application. The .exe file is signed and works perfectly in Windows XP. I am only receiving these errors in Vista x86/x64. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this an issue 32/64 bit? Do you have a 64 bit version?

Comment: Same issue in 32 or 64 bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter if I run the process as an Administrator or just a regular user - the same thing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a UIPI issue:

> User Interface Privilege Isolation
>   (UIPI) implements restrictions in the
>   windows subsystem that prevents
>   lower-privilege applications from
>   sending window messages or **installing
>   hooks** in higher-privilege processes.

from Microsoft's [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)

Comment: The strange thing is that it works fine until I copy the files to the "Program Files" folder. I haven't been able to find any docs that say that folder is more restrictive.

Comment: Search the article for "Program Files" and you'll see that there is at least one rule that might explain the difference between Desktop and Program Files.

Comment: According to that article, the only way it should work is when it is in the "Program Files" folder, but I'm seeing the opposite behaviour. :(

Comment: Have you tried implementing the UIAccess security attribute as described in the article?

Comment: I have. I have a manifest file embedded in the application and the DLLs. I have it set to "asInvoker" and "UIAccess=true".

Comment: Have you checked the return value of SetWindowsHookEx?

Comment: If SetWindowsHookEx is not returning an error, run Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see if you DLL is getting loaded into other processes.