# c++ get other windows messages

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, message

im learning to make things to other windows like resize the ie or any type of window. the only problem i don't know how i can get or give messages to other windows.
so like i pressed a key in ie i would like to get that message to my program too!
any idea

Comment: -1 for "im trying to create keylogger".  We're not here to help you steal passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the messages that are sent to windows programs you have to install a hook in order to listen to the messages you want. You do this via the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) function.

However, I believe that you should read a book about this kind of behaviour, since there are certain rules you have to apply. For instance, before returning from your callback function, you have to call [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644974(VS.85).aspx) in order to let the other hooks handle the message. [This is the first hit](http://books.google.com/books?id=5Cs46M9FV0sC&pg=PA485&dq=setwindowshookex&hl=sv&ei=FC-ITNyZHorqOPLk0YAO&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=setwindowshookex&f=false) in books.google.com when searching for setwindowshookex.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your application won't receive Windows messages for other applications (this can be a security problem, for example with keylogger spyware). However, the [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx) method can be used to install a hook that receives other window message inputs.

However, note that a Windows feature called [UIPI can cause problems with CBT hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936830/cbt-hook-not-working-in-windows-vista).

Comment: im trying to create keylogger