# How to record keystrokes on Windows [C++]

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to record keystrokes (if user pressed 'ABCS', I wand that saved in a string) if the user switches to a certain window which is name is AAA, the windows is not of the current application, but can be of any other one.

I guess I know how to get the current window name, its something like that:

```
#include <windows.h>

// ...

TCHAR buf[255];
GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), buf, 255);
```

But how to record the keys, I have no idea.

Thanks,

Comment: I've often wondered if we should close questions like this because they seem to be nefarious.

Comment: @John:  You're joking right?  We're here to help people solve programming problems, not judge peoples intentions.

Comment: it has a good purpose, not all keyloggers have to be malicious

Comment: @PigBen:  It was just a vovalization of what I was thinking.  I'm sure others have thought it as well.  I didnt vote to close.

Comment: You can check the answers in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672533/238902 "c++ get other windows messages") as well

Comment: @soulsurfers - "not all keyloggers are malicious"?  Really?  I'd like to hear of one.

Comment: @Tim okay, I made a keylogger to record the most used words when typing a string of characters to create a auto-correct for my desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use the [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a thread id from a window handle.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this sample! http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=11920&lngWId=3

Answer (score 0):

This *may not* be what you are looking for, but just in case you are trying to create "hotkeys", Win32 has direct support for it - see `RegisterHotkey`

And there is `SetWindowsHookEx`